# adjust the width of table column

Tags: multicolumn, width, column-width

I'm trying to make the third column of this table wider, so any suggestions to adjust the third column for a better look?

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage{booktabs,xltabular}
 \newcommand{\SPESGindex}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape SP 500 ESG index}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\POL}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Pollution }}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\INF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Inflation}}\nolimits} 
 \newcommand{\REC}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Recession }}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\GPR}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Geopolitical risk}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\EPU}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Economic policy uncertainty (USA)}}\nolimits} 
\newcommand{\NSI}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape New-based sentiment index}}\nolimits} 
 \newcommand{\PRI}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Physical risk index}}\nolimits} 
 \newcommand{\TRI}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Transition risk index}}\nolimits} 
 \newcommand{\MCCC}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Media and Climate Change Concerns}}\nolimits} 


\begin{document}

 %------------------------------------------------
\begin{table}
\caption{Variables and measurement\label{appendix}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lXXS@{}}
 \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Symbol}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Variable Description}&\multicolumn{1}{p{0.5cm}} 
{Measure}\\
  \midrule
   \SPESGindex  & SP 500 ESG index        &  The S\&P 500 ESG Index is intended to be a market 
 capitalization-weighted index with a wide base that measures the performance of securities fulfilling sustainability standards while keeping comparable sector weights overall to the underlying index. Source. Bloomberg. \\
 \POL         & POL                      &  Average number of daily searches on Google Trends for the phrase "pollution" in the Unites States. Source: Google trends.\\

\INF         & INF                      &  Average number of daily searches on Google Trends for the phrase "inflation" in the United States. Source: Google trends..\\

   \REC         & REC                      &   Average number of times the phrase "recession" is searched for each day on Google Trends in the United States. Source: Google trends.\\

  \GPR         & GPR                     & The GPR index reflects the occurrence of words related to geopolitical tensions in leading international newspapers. Source: Caldara and Iacoviello (2022).\\

 \EPU         & EPU                     &T his index measures the frequency of certain phrases that represent uncertainty about the economic policy environment in newspaper stories to quantify the uncertainty of economic policy. Source: Backer et al (2016).\\

 \NSI         & NSI                     & The Daily News Sentiment Index is a quantitative indicator that gauges economic sentiment by using lexical analysis techniques on news stories specifically relevant to economics.  Source: Shapiro et al. (2020)..\\

\PRI         & PRI                      & Physical risks refer to the potential financial implications that can arise due to changes in the climate. These risks can be event-driven (acute)Source. Bua et al. (2022) .\\

\TRI         & TRI                     & Transition risks are associated with the financial implications that arise from the process of transitioning to a lower-carbon economy.\\

\MCCC        & MCCC                    & This index captures news articles related to climate change from U.S. newspapers and newswires between January 1, 2003, and June 30, 2018. Source: Bua et al (2022). .\\

 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can try `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{$}l<{$}lX@{}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `\mathop` is doing: you're getting tons of errors, which you should not disregard. Also there is no `S` column.

Reduce the width of the second column by splitting the header into two lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\SPESGindex}{\textnormal{\slshape SP 500 ESG index}}
\newcommand{\POL}{\textnormal{\slshape Pollution }}
\newcommand{\INF}{\textnormal{\slshape Inflation}} 
\newcommand{\REC}{\textnormal{\slshape Recession }}
\newcommand{\GPR}{\textnormal{\slshape Geopolitical risk}}
\newcommand{\EPU}{\textnormal{\slshape Economic policy uncertainty (USA)}} 
\newcommand{\NSI}{\textnormal{\slshape New-based sentiment index}} 
\newcommand{\PRI}{\textnormal{\slshape Physical risk index}} 
\newcommand{\TRI}{\textnormal{\slshape Transition risk index}} 
\newcommand{\MCCC}{\textnormal{\slshape Media and Climate Change Concerns}} 

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2][t]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{Variables and measurement}\label{appendix}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lcX@{}}
\toprule
Symbol & \splitcell{Variable \\ Description} & Measure \\
\midrule
\SPESGindex  & \splitcell{SP 500 ESG \\ index} &
  The S\&P 500 ESG Index is intended to be a market capitalization-weighted
  index with a wide base that measures the performance of securities fulfilling
  sustainability standards while keeping comparable sector weights overall to
  the underlying index.
  Source. Bloomberg. \\

\POL & POL &
  Average number of daily searches on Google Trends for the phrase ``pollution''
  in the Unites States.
  Source: Google trends. \\

\INF & INF &
  Average number of daily searches on Google Trends for the phrase ``inflation''
  in the United States.
  Source: Google trends. \\

\REC & REC &
  Average number of times the phrase ``recession'' is searched for each day on
  Google Trends in the United States.
  Source: Google trends. \\

\GPR & GPR &
  The GPR index reflects the occurrence of words related to geopolitical
  tensions in leading international newspapers.
  Source: Caldara and Iacoviello (2022). \\

\EPU & EPU &
  This index measures the frequency of certain phrases that represent
  uncertainty about the economic policy environment in newspaper stories
  to quantify the uncertainty of economic policy.
  Source: Backer et al.\ (2016). \\

\NSI & NSI &
  The Daily News Sentiment Index is a quantitative indicator that gauges
  economic sentiment by using lexical analysis techniques on news stories
  specifically relevant to economics.
  Source: Shapiro et al.\ (2020). \\

\PRI & PRI &
  Physical risks refer to the potential financial implications that can
  arise due to changes in the climate. These risks can be event-driven
  (acute).
  Source. Bua et al.\ (2022). \\

\TRI & TRI &
  Transition risks are associated with the financial implications that
  arise from the process of transitioning to a lower-carbon economy.
  \\

\MCCC & MCCC &
  This index captures news articles related to climate change from U.S.
  newspapers and newswires between January 1, 2003, and June 30, 2018.
  Source: Bua et al.\ (2022). \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Are you sure you're not confusing “variable description“ with “symbol”?

A tip: never use `"` for quotes, see the edited code: you want ``` `` ``` for opening quotes and `''` for closing ones.

I also fixed a few inconsistencies: double or missing periods and “backslash space” after non sentence ending periods (in “et al.”).

Comment: perfect, this is what I'm looking for!  yeah, you are right,  it should be the inverse, I'm confusing about the symbol and variable description!